# ASP.NET SearchBox for web page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

so I have an empty web page, with a button and a Label, when the button is clicked the label is filled with data from my database.
I am new to asp.net , so I would like to know is there any way I can add a search box in the page , that I can search for data that is displayed in the Label.

Example: I have list of cities in the Label and I want to see where is the city LONDON.

I will provide some images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need explain more about your question like if you are using LINQ add to your question, it can help for better answer.

Comment: @NEBEZ  On button click, I pull my data using NEST library the data  is Elastic Search database, and provide it in a label.

Comment: Ok, but edit your question and add this details for more generating and users can help.

Answer (score 1):

A way to change style of a html element using javascript would be the following:

```
<input type="text" id="SearchBox" onInput="OnSearchTextDidChange()">

<ul>
<li id="London">London</li>
<li id="Paris">Paris</li>
<li id="Sweden">Sweden</li>
<li id="Europe">Europe</li> 
</ul>


<script>

htmlIds = ["London", "Paris", "Sweden", "Europe"];


function OnSearchTextDidChange(){
    var text = document.getElementById("SearchBox").value.toString();

    for(var i = 0; i < htmlIds.length;i++){
       if(htmlIds[i] == text){
            document.getElementById(htmlIds[i]).style.color = "yellow"; 
       }
       else{
            document.getElementById(htmlIds[i]).style.color = "black";
       }
}

}

</script>
```

Be aware that this solution is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

make a an html input element, and handle the input from user with javascript:

```
<input type="text" onInput="OnSearchTextDidChange()">



<script>
function OnSearchTextDidChange(){
//do what you want when search text changes

}
</script>
```

Comment: what do I need to put so the searched text is highlighted